# How to put caption on the side of two figures in a column?

Tags: captions

could you give me ideas about how to put the caption on the side of two figures in a column? I know how to put the caption on the side of a figure here. But how to put the caption on the left of the two figures in the example below?

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images1} \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images2}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{This is the caption on the left}
\label{fig:ctime}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `floatrow` package as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption{This is the caption on the left}\label{fig:ctime}}
{\begin{tabular}{c}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{name}\\ \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{name}\end{tabular}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: cool, it works. Thanks a lot!