# How to put the caption to the side of a figure containing subfigures?

Tags: subcaption, sidecap

I would like to create a figure containing subfigures and a caption to the side as shown below.

[image: Image of a captioned figure containing six subfigures]

I have everything as shown except that the caption is below the subfigures instead of to the left of them. I am using the package subcaption with the subfigure command. I tried to use the package sidecap but subcaptions do not appear to work within an SCFigure.

I am using overleaf in case that is relevant.

My current markup:

```
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption{}
        \label{figure:my figure 1}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 1.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.15\linewidth}
        \caption{}
        \label{figure:my figure 2}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 2.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.15\linewidth}
        \label{figure:my figure 3}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 3.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.15\linewidth}
        \label{figure:my figure 4}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 4.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A collection of related images}
    \label{figure:my figure}
\end{figure}
```

Related questions:

- [How to put caption on the side of two figures in a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546371/)
- [How to insert a main caption beside subfigures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186766/how-to-insert-a-main-caption-beside-subfigures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following `minipage`-based approach? (Vertical lines indicate the margins.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the demo option in your real document.
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
        \caption{A collection of related images}
        \label{figure:my figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\linewidth}
        \caption{}
        \label{figure:my figure 1}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 1.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\linewidth}
        \caption{}
        \label{figure:my figure 2}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 2.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\linewidth}
        \caption{}
        \label{figure:my figure 2}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 2.png}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{0.5em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\linewidth}
        \label{figure:my figure 3}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 3.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\linewidth}
        \label{figure:my figure 4}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 4.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.1em}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.3\linewidth}
        \label{figure:my figure 4}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my figure 4.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.